# Solving exponent on both side of equation

Tags: exponential-function

I'm new here on Mathematics and have only basic algebraic knowledge. I have a problem in how to solve the following equation:
$$ P^x = R_0^x + R_1^x + ... +R_n^x $$
I know the value of P and the values of all $R$'s. Sometimes there are only two $R$'s but can also be $3, 4$ or $5$ $R$'s.

How do I solve for $x$? Is this possible trough algebra?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In general no, it is not possible to manipulate the symbols to get x = . you will need to use a numerical method like the Bisection Method or Newton's Method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into the bisection and newton's method

Comment: you could plot graphs of $y = P^x$ and $y=R_0^x+...R_n^x$ to start with. Where they cross is the x value you want. This will let you know you are on the right track with your solution and give you good starting values for a numerical method.

Comment: Can you tell us anything about the relative values of $P$ and the $R$'s ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting $P^x=t$, the equation turns to

$$t=t^{\alpha_0}+t^{\alpha_1}+\cdots t^{\alpha_n}$$ where

$$\alpha_k=\frac{\log(R_k)}{\log(P)}.$$

Such "generalized polynomial" equations are known to have no solutions in radicals for rational exponents, in general.

Even with two $R$'s there is no analytical solution (except for very specific values of the $\alpha$'s). In practice, you will have to resort to numerical methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into nummerical methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use a numerical method. I'd suggest using something like the [secant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) or [Brent's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent's_method) method, as they don't require derivatives (they get messy with such an expression, and costly to compute). Starting points could be taking, with the $R_i$ in increasing order:

$\begin{align}
P^x &= R_1^x + \dotsb + R_n^x \\
1   &= \left(\frac{R_1}{P}\right)^x + \dotsb + \left(\frac{R_n}{P}\right)^x
\end{align}$

Rough bounds should be the solutions of:

$\begin{align}
1 &= n \left(\frac{R_1}{P}\right)^{x_a} \\
1 &= n \left(\frac{R_n}{P}\right)^{x_b}
\end{align}$

Or just ask your tame computer algebra system to solve it numerically for you.